# Positioning text over scalable image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
#hero-container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 520px;
}

.hero {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
  
#text {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 150px;
    top: 40px;
}
    
#text2 {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 150px;
    top: 70px;
}
    
#hero-container img {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="hero-container">
      <img class="hero" src="https://vreauperle.ro/images/banners/hero-image.jpg"></img>
      <p id="text">
        First text here
      </p>
      <p id="text2">
        Secondary
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have an image with **width:100%**, in a fixed container. Because my image resizes, the text doesn't follow and stays in the same position, thus moving over the container.

How do I make the text stay in the center of the image (vertically) and to the left, with a few pixels padding (horizontally) without adding 1000 media queries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can greatly simplify your CSS:

1. Remove the flex (unless there is some specific reason you need it).
2. Wrap the text you want centred vertically in a `div` and `translateY(-50%)`.
3. Make sure the wrapper around the image has `position:relative`.

```css
#hero-container {
  position: relative;
}

#center-text {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 15%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
  
#text {
  font-size: 3vw;
  margin: 0;
}
    
#text2 {
  font-size: 2vw;
  margin: 0;
}
    
#hero-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="hero-container">
  <img class="hero" src="https://vreauperle.ro/images/banners/hero-image.jpg" />
  <div id="center-text">
    <p id="text">
      First text here
    </p>
    <p id="text2">
      Secondary
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will be fully responsive no matter your resolution and should work in IE10+ (or IE9+ with `-ms-transform` prefix), if you use some more standard font-size (instead of `vw`).

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the **left** and **top** css property in terms of **'%'** instead of **'px'** then you will get the result. [Fiddle Is Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4376eh8e/3/)

```css
#hero-container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    height: 520px;
  }

  .hero {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  #text {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 30%;
    top: 0;
  }
    
    #text2 {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 30%;
    top: 11%;
    }
    
    #hero-container img {
    display: flex;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="hero-container">
   <img class="hero" src="https://vreauperle.ro/images/banners/hero-image.jpg"></img>
   <div class='txt_wrap'>
          <p id="text">
    First text here
   </p>
   <p id="text2">
    Secondary
   </p>
      </div>
      
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Open the page on a larger screen, or go to expand snippet. Text is mixed together. You need to provide some padding between text1 and text2

Answer (score 0):

Code to align element vertically and horizontally center.

```
  p {
     position : absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     }
```

In your case, since you only want vertically center, remove left:50% and use translateY(-50%).

Answer (score 0):

You could display the image as a `background-image` of `#hero-container`.

Then you have no need to use `position: absolute` on the text.

You can add `padding` to the container in a percentage value - this will scale better than fixed pixels. You can edit the value I have used in the snippet to something that will work for you.

```css
#hero-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 520px;
  background: url(https://vreauperle.ro/images/banners/hero-image.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 5%;
}

#hero-container p {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

#text {
  font-size: 3vw;
  
}

#text2 {
  font-size: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="hero-container">
  <p id="text">
    First text here
  </p>
  <p id="text2">
    Secondary
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Close but I believe OP wants text to be centered no matter what viewport. See Jonathans answer